# DKIM signing - does it matter which transport agent does the signature

Tags: exchange, email-server, dkim

I am quite new to the dkim area. I understand how it works but some details, i am missing.

Let's say, i have a mail server that contains user boxes (Exchange) and an edge server that just transports the email (an old cisco antispam) which does only one job, relays incoming messages to exchange and outgoing messages wherever they are destined.

*The question is, where should the signing occur?*

From what I read, typically when people have exchange with edge role, they suggest sign there.But does that really matter (I would prefer doing it right on the exchange as the cisco device is way too old and might cause issues)?

I understand that the cisco might add some headers and thus alter the message but (from what i understand), the signature should apply only to certain portions of an email message (from, subject, to, date, message-id).

Comment: Your Cisco antispam device isn't an Exchange edge transport server, it's an SMTP relay. If you're concerned, why not just perform the DKIM signing on the Exchange server and be done with it?

Answer (score -1):

It is true that DKIM signatures are typically applied to specific parts of an email, such as the From, Subject, To, Date, and Message ID fields.
In terms of where to apply a DKIM signature, it is generally recommended to apply it as close to the source of the message as possible. This is to ensure that the signature covers as many messages as possible and to minimize the possibility of any intermediary system changing the message in a way that renders the signature invalid.

In this case, if your Exchange server has an edge role, it would be better to apply the DKIM signature on the Exchange server itself rather than on the older Cisco device.